# Find the maximum list item in a loop, number of occurrences

Tags: python

I have a code. It works. But there is one problem. The search for the maximum item in the list is performed using the max function. How can I rewrite this code so that the search for the maximum element occurs in a loop without using the max function?

I would be very grateful for your help. Newbie to Python.

```
import random

spisok = []

for i in range(0,5):
    spisok.append(random.randint(1,25))

maxi = max(spisok)

a = sorted(spisok, reverse=True)

print('Such numbers are generated: ')
print(spisok)
print('In decreasing order: ')
print(a)

for num, i in enumerate(a, 1):
    print('{cout} maximum: {maxim}'.format(maxim = i, cout = num))
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason not to use `max`?

Comment: your `a[0]` , will have the max value in your list

Comment: What have you tried so far? What specific problems did you encounter and need help with?

Answer (score 0):

this would work, but using `max` is highly recommended due to performance and readability

```
max=0
for i in spisok:
    if i> max:
        max=i
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah,You can perform max inside the loop by taking a variable and comparing the max variable with generated variable then update the max variable.

```py
import random

spisok = []

maxi=0

for i in range(0,5):
    randomNumber = random.randint(1,25)
    spisok.append(randomNumber)
    if maxi < randomNumber:
        maxi=randomNumber
print(maxi)
```